# jQuery slideDown function doesn't work but fadeIn does

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidedown

I am relatively new to jQuery. I have been combing through already answered questions but can't seem to find what's wrong with my code.

I have a set of png files I am displaying on a website. For one, I use the .fadeIn() function and it works. For another, I want the image to drop down from the top of the window and I am using the .slideDown() function for this. The fadeIn() works perfectly but the slideDown doesn't do anything to the image for some reason. I have tried setting display:none; in my CSS but it still doesn't seem to do the trick. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>


  <body>

  <div class="row" id="sky">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-offset-0" > <img src="stars.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Stars" style="position: absolute;" > </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="treeline">

    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-0" > <img src="yard2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Yard" > </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="row">
   <div id="neighborhood">
      <div id = "tallhouse" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1"> <img src="tallhouseCC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Tall House" style="position: absolute;"> </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2" > <img src="greenhouseCC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Green House" style="position: absolute;"> </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2" > <img src="centerhouseCC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Center House" style="position: absolute;"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2" > <img src="italianhouseCC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Italian House" style="position: absolute;"> </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2" > <img src="tealhouseCC.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Teal House" style="position: absolute;"> </div>

    </div>
  </div>




    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tallhouse").slideDown("slow");
        $("#sky").fadeIn(2000);
      });
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  min-height: 400px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: #0B0B3B; 
}

.navbar {
   background-color: transparent;
   background: transparent;
   border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar li { color: #000 } 

#tallhouse{
    display: none;
}

#neighborhoodsky{
    min-height: 150px;
}

#neighborhood{
  padding-top: 260px;
  display: none;
}

#sky{
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    display: none;
}

#treeline{
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 270px;
  min-height: 30px;
  top:-3%;
}
```

The #sky id is done the same way as the #tallhouse id so I don't know why it isn't working. I'm fairly new to this community so I understand this might be a redundant question but I haven't been able to find a solution through research. Please don't light me up lol

Comment: you have that img inside #tallhouse with absolute position then the container divs height is 0 ... and will "slide" to nothing.

Comment: Does that mean i need to specify a height for the #tallhouse in the CSS?

Comment: If you want to keep the absolute yes .... https://jsfiddle.net/ua2wrLL4/1/

Comment: Im sorry, I still don't follow. I don't see a height specification in the cs portion of the jsfiddle

Comment: That fiddle just remove the absolute position ... to keep it absolute check this https://jsfiddle.net/ua2wrLL4/2/

Comment: @DaniP I made the edits but it still didn't seem to solve the problem. I pasted the entire code now though, the problem might have been that I didn't provide everything. Do you see anything new?

Comment: Add to your tallhouse position-relative and height fixed

Comment: @DaniP I removed the position absolute and added position relative and height fixed to the css, but when i reload the page there is still no effect for the png. Do you think the problem might be outside of the code?

Comment: @DaniP if there is a way to send you a video of what's going on I would, I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong with it